# ERROR: unknown builder: no builders found for group: myorg/my-builder-name on docker buildx create --driver cloud

Tags: docker, docker-compose, buildx

I'm trying to install the brand new docker cloud builder on my RaspberryPi with the hope a lot of build parts will run now in the cloud instead of the Pi.
I am following the doc here: https://docs.docker.com/build/cloud/setup/

- I installed the latest buildx and compose binaries and tested their versions are good:

```
$ docker buildx version
github.com/docker/buildx v0.12.1-desktop.3 98086793f1408a600da93bb7211247d6a95bec20
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.23.3-desktop.2
```

Then I logged in with `docker login` and finally tried the command:
`docker buildx create --driver cloud <my-org>/my-builder`
and I get the error: `ERROR: unknown builder: no builders found for group: <my-org>/my-builder` which is weird as I am precisely trying to create it.

Any idea? Or am I missing something?

EDIT: when I say `<my-org>`, I actually use my docker hub account name

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work!

Go to https://build.docker.com/accounts/YourAccountName/builders

Define a new builder there.
Then try the create again with the name of the builder you just defined!

If you have problems, https://build.docker.com might be a better starting point.

You just need to define a builder on the cloud before you can docker buildx create it

Comment: Thanks @rustyshamrock. Actually, one builder was already created on the site, I don't understand why and I copy pasted the commmand line given on the site after clicking on the builder and it worked. Strange